# How to assign default values to a function arguments at the run-time in C#

Tags: c#, function, arguments

I have the following class:

```
public class Location
{
    private int X { get; set; }
    private int Y { get; set; }
    private int Z { get; set; }

    public UpdateLocation(int X, int Y, int Z)
    {
        this.X = X;
        this.Y = Y;
        this.Z = Z;
    }
}
```

However, sometimes I need to update some of these arguments and to all. so I was thinking of a way to initialize the function's arguments than assign them to the local variables like in:

```
public UpdateLocation(int X = this.X, int Y = this.Y, int Z = this.Z)
{
    this.X = X;
    this.Y = Y;
    this.Z = Z;
}
```

So I can call the function like this:

```
UpdateLocation(Z:1509);
```

But obviously, that won't work since the arguments default values have to be compile-time constants. any idea how to solve this without creating three different updating functions (or maybe more) to update these variables?

Comment: create one more class and create properties for the parameters that you want

Comment: why not overriding your `public UpdateLocation` and create the cases you need?

Comment: You could make the parameters nullable (Int32?) and assigne a default value of null to them. Check for each parameter if it is not null before you assign its value to your properties: (if(x.HasValue)X=x.Value;)

Comment: @musium you should have posted that as answer...

Comment: Maybe you can write `Location.Z = 1509` instead of calling that method.

Comment: That requires 6 different override functions for UpdateLocation !!!
UpdateLocation(int X), UpdateLocation(int Y), UpdateLocation(int Z), UpdateLocation(int X, int Y), UpdateLocation(int Y, int Z), UpdateLocation(int X, int Z)
I was wishing to find more efficint way to write the function.

Comment: @Alexei Levenkov ... I know... but I'm currently writing on a phone... and writing a full answer on a phone is a huge pain^^

Answer (score 3, accepted):

default parameters must be initialized with null or constant value.

```
public UpdateLocation(int? X = null, int? Y = null, int? Z = null)
{
    if(X.HasValue) this.X = X.Value;
    if(Y.HasValue) this.Y = Y.Value;
    if(Z.HasValue) this.Z = Z.Value;

    // this.X = X ?? this.X;
    // this.Y = Y ?? this.Y;
    // this.Z = Z ?? this.Z;
}
```

Now choose to update

```
UpdateLocation(Y: 5, X: 2);
```

[Here you can read about named arguments.](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd264739.aspx)

Comment: I can't call it like that! I think I still need to send three parameters (null for those I want to keep their info) 
UpdateLocation(X:10, Y:null, null);

Comment: You can. Any argument with default values can be omitted. And you can directly assign whichever argument you want using named arguments like he has.

Comment: @SaajidAkram you don't have to do that. `UpdateLocation(Y: 5, X: 2);` works for me just fine. if you want to pass all three parameter just do UpdateLocation(5, 3, 0). but if you want to choose parameters this way should work.

Comment: @SaajidAkram I appreciate to see the problem. maybe if you post screen shot where you get syntax error.

Comment: Super, you are right ... I forgot to add null as a default value to the vars :/ .... I was quite nerves ...thanks my friend, really appreciate it :)

Answer (score 5):

```
public UpdateLocation(int? X = null, int? Y = null, int? Z = null)
{
    this.X = X ?? this.X;
    this.Y = Y ?? this.Y;
    this.Z = Z ?? this.Z;
}
```

You could also just set the properties.

Comment: I think properties would be better. Easier to read than this function calls in few weeks.

Comment: Good. But in this way, I need to change this.X, this.Y, this.Z also to nullable vars!!

Comment: No you don't. ?? Is the null coalesce operator. It means if X is null assign this.X instead.

Answer (score 2):

Nullable Integers are fine options, appreciate those answers, You can try  something like this as well:

```
public const int minInt = int.MinValue;

public void UpdateLocation(int X = minInt, int Y = minInt, int Z = minInt)
{
    this.X = X == minInt ? this.X : X;
    this.Y = Y == minInt ? this.Y : Y;
    this.Z = Z == minInt ? this.Z : Z; ;
}
```